# Apache Camel Rest DSL DirectConsumerNotAvailableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, servlets, apache-camel

I have set up an Apache Camel REST API with Springboot using Servlets and Spring XML. I am using JBoss EAP to deploy the API via a war file. Below is the site I am referencing:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html

The code successfully builds and deploys. However, when I try to access the endpoint URL (*http://localhost:8080/camel-rest-cxfrs-jaxrs/api/customers?country=abc)*, I get the following exceptions:

> Exception handling request to /camel-rest-cxfrs-jaxrs/api/customers:
> org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during
> execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-localhost-
>
> at
> org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846)
> at
> org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:713)
> at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515)
> at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511)
> at
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:338)
> at org.test.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:50)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://start. Exchange[ID-localhost-

Have I missed something, or set up the configuration wrong?

Below is my file structure and source code:

**File Structure:**

[image]

**jboss-camel-context.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <bean class="org.test.MyBean" id="helloBean"/>
    <camelContext id="camelContext-0476f574-9dab-47b1-89dd-e87e0c6ba735" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <restConfiguration component="servlet" bindingMode="auto"/>
        
        <rest path="/api/customers">
            <get>
                <route>
                    <from uri="direct:start"/>
                    <to uri="direct:start"/>
                </route>
            </get>
            <post>
                <route>
                    <to uri="file:output/customers"/>
                </route>
            </post>
        </rest>

        <rest path="/customers">
            <delete uri="{id}">
                <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=delete(${header.id})"/>
            </delete>
        </rest>
        <rest path="/getapi">
            <get uri="/search?country={country}">
                <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=byCountry(${header.country})"/>
            </get>
        </rest>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
    @WebServlet(name = "HttpServiceServlet", urlPatterns = { "/*" }, loadOnStartup = 1)
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Resource(name = "java:jboss/camel/context/spring-context")
        private CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    
            try {
                camelContext.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String name = req.getParameter("country");
            ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
            ProducerTemplate producer = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
            String result = producer.requestBody("direct:start", name, String.class);
            out.print(result);
            //camelContext.stop();
        }
    }
```

**MyBean.java**

```
public class MyBean {

    public String sayHello(String message) {        
       return "Hello " + message;   
    }

    public String delete(String id) {
       return "Deleted Customer = " + id;   
    }

    public String byCountry(String countryName) {
       System.out.println("Hello World " + countryName);        
       return "Hello World";    
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The immediate problem, I think, is that you have a route for which both the "to" and "from" endpoints are `direct:start`. I'm not sure what that's supposed to do. You seem to be mixing camel-cxf stuff with camel-rest stuff in the same application. An example of doing camel-cxf with a servlet as input is here: https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel-examples/tree/master/camel-cxf-jaxrs

Comment: I want to move away from camel-cxf and have a Camel Rest DSL with the servlet component instead. I'm mainly using the following tutorial: https://tomd.xyz/camel-rest/ 
However, I'm not sure where the restConfiguration() block would go; in the MyServlet.java class?